# How to add structuremap container configuration to Web Api Startup file

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a StructureMap container already set up (in a separate project) like so:

```
    public class Container
    {
        public static StructureMap.Container Current { get; private set; }

        public static void InitIoC()
        {
            var container = new StructureMap.Container(
                c =>
                {
                    c.For<AppSettings>().Singleton();
                    c.For<ILogger>().Use<Logger>();
                    c.For<IReminderService>().Use<ReminderService>();
                    ...
                }
       }
    }
```

I would like this configuration to be used in .NET Core 2.0 Web API.

In my Startup.cs I have to do this to make it work:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(ILogger), typeof(Logger)));
        ... // rewriting what is already configured
    }
```

How can I simply inject this same configuration into WebAPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();                      
        //Create StructureMap container
        var container = new Container(); //This is Structuremap's container class, not your custom class
        container.Configure(config =>
        {
            //Add in your custom structuremap registry
            config.AddRegistry(new Container());
            //Push the .net Core Services Collection into StructureMap
            config.Populate(services);
        });
        //Register dependencies
        services.ConfigureDependencies();
        //Return the service provider
        return container.GetInstance<IServiceProvider>();
    }
```

I don't know if it's necessary but you can change your `Container` class be like:

```
public class Container: Registry
    {
        public Container()
        {               
           c.For<ILogger>().Use<Logger>();
           c.For<IReminderService>().Use<ReminderService>();
           //More mappings
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep. a little change here and there but it works. Thanks